# Sonata 2011 2.4 liter fuel filter location

Tags: hyundai, sonata, fuel-filter

Where is the fuel filter located for the 2011 Sonata 2.4 L?
How do you change it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The fuel filter is part of the fuel pump inside the gas tank, it is not serviceable and only gets changed when the pump is changed.